# Smoothing with keeping min/max values

Tags: mean, moving-average

I want to smooth GPS elevation data to reliably sum the ascents of my hikes and training runs. For example, it registers these elevation values:

```
602, 602, 601, 602, 601, 602, 614, 607, 602
```

I can smooth out the flukes (`602 --> 601 --> 602 --> 601 --> 602`) with a moving median (or average) value - with rounding, if necessary. But then, the elevation of 614 will be discarded.

Is there a reliable way to smooth a data series while keeping local minimums and maximums?

Comment: What makes a sequence of similar values "flukes" compared to an isolated outlying value??

Comment: @whuber It's the rounding my GPS device is doing. When the "true" altitude hovers around 601.5 meters, the altitude gets rounded to either 601 or 602. Which means I have frequent ascents of 1 meter. But when the altitude hovers around 602, it gets rounded to 602, and there are rarely artificial ascents. That's why I like to smooth them out. Compared to the real track (GPS waypoints overlaid on a topographical map), the ascents can be inflated by about 170%